# Finding trouble in links in html not working

Tags: html, css

```
<body >
    <div class="outer-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
               <a href="#">HOME</a>
               <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
               <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
               <a href="">RESUME</a>
            </div>
            <div class="big-heading">
                <h2 style=color:white>
                   I'm Ankit Soni.
                </h2>
            </div>

            <div class="social-media">
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ankit-soni-991495152/">
                    <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://github.com/ankysony">
                    <i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
                    <a href="mailto:ankit.soni.che16@iitbhu.ac.in">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
            </div>  
            <div class="scrolldown">
                <a href="">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I cannot find any type of mistake in it but my links in it are not working (no cursor pointer no redirects). Only the last one with arrow circle is working. The links under class social-media are not.

I got a part of css which is creating the error please see to it and suggest the possible way to fix error.

```
.outer-container .container .big-heading
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

**and the entire css code is below.**

```
 *
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.outer-container
{
    height: 792px;
    width: 1440px;
}
h2{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
html {
    background: url(../images/banner.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
.outer-container .container .header
{
    text-align: center;
    word-spacing: 100px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.outer-container .container .header a 
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.outer-container .container .big-heading
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
.outer-container .container .social-media
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
} 
.outer-container .container .social-media i
{
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.outer-container .container .scrolldown
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 300px;
}
 .outer-container .container .scrolldown i
{
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working? what exactly is happening

Comment: The links inside the `<div class="header">` element do not have a href which will do anything.  What are you expecting to happen?
There are no links inside `<div class="big-heading">`

Comment: By working do you mean not directing you to the correct page, or not showing up?

Comment: it is showing the icon but my cursor is neither changing to hand and neither it is taking me to other page

Comment: @adamgy it is not showing up.

Comment: @AUSteve by mistake i typed big-heading class

Comment: @AUSteve I meant to say class social-media

Answer (score 0):

In the `header` class, your `href` is not redirecting you anywhere, because you only specified `href="#"`, which neither points to another page nor points to any specific id on your page. You should add your url to to navigate to another page (or, in this case maybe an id on your own page):

```
href="www.site.com"
```

Also, it seems like in the `social-media` class, you did not specify any text for the link, which is why they aren't showing up.
You should put some text between the opening and closing tags:

```
<a href="url">link text</a>
```

Comment: I have not typed any link in header, but my concern is that even the cursor is not changing to that hand with one finger.

Comment: and in social-media class, I want to make that font awesome image as a link, but its not happening

Comment: I think you you try to use some tools like [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools) to debug your css to find out why your links don't show the cursor pointer. Regarding your image, if you're talking about fa fa-arrow-circle-down, you should add the url to your href.

Answer (score 0):

Cursor: pointer is showing and working fine in your code, to get font awesome work you need to include the library of font awesome.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body >
    <div class="outer-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
               <a href="#">HOME</a>
               <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
               <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
               <a href="">RESUME</a>
            </div>
            <div class="big-heading">
                <h2 style=color:white>
                   I'm Ankit Soni.
                </h2>
            </div>

            <div class="social-media">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ankit-soni-991495152/">
                    <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/ankysony">
                    <i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
                    <a target="_blank" href="mailto:ankit.soni.che16@iitbhu.ac.in">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
            </div>  
            <div class="scrolldown">
                <a href="">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: ya the html part is fine the problem is in css

Comment: you have 2 requirements in your question, 1. link need to be working and 2, font awesome icon need to shown, both are working in my example. what else you need... maybe I got the wrong idea

Comment: they are not working once i am clubing css file with it

Comment: Make sure that you don't apply pointer-events:none; on anchor anywhere in your css